# Scrolling to the bottom of a div which get opened via jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I try to scroll to the bottom of a Div which get opened via jquery toggle.

I tried it like this:

```
    $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".menuitem").click(function() {
            $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub').toggle(1000);
            $('html, body').animate({"scrollTop": $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub').offset().top}, 'fast');
    }
);
```

With the code after scrollTop: `$('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub')` i get the right id of the div which got expanded from the toggle.

The Problem: I'm on the top of the div and not on the bottom so the user can't see the content - only the first line. I somehow have to add the final size of the div to the scroll but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the height of the element and add it to the scroll

```
 $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub').offset().top 
 + $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub').height()
```

however you need to do this after your element has been displayed otherwise it won't get the correct height so add it to the toggle callback like so:

```
$(".menuitem").click(function() {
    $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub').toggle(1000, function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            "scrollTop": $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub').offset().top
                       + $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+'sub').height()
        }, 'fast')
    });
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem - scrolled to the top because the height at the moment I fire the animate event is still 0 because it hasn't finished the expanding animation from the toggle. Any idea?

Comment: yes, do the scroll in the toggle callback, I will change my answer :)

Comment: It's really too late (3:14am) to do something productive - i forget even the easiest things. Thanks ;)

Comment: changed my answer :) if you want to scroll to the middle of the div (so users see content, just divide the height by 2)

Comment: somehow the callback function didn't get the scroll - nothing happened o.O

Comment: I think it has to do with $(this) not referencing the $(".menuitem") but $('html, body'). is the id attribute on the menuitem or html body ?

Comment: it's on the html,body - it's on the same level like the .menuitem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40686/discussion-between-yussuf-s-and-domi)